# Symfony: include MappedSuperClass form inside another Form Type

Tags: forms, symfony, mappedsuperclass

in Symfony 6, I have a `MappedSuperclass` Entity called `Person` with personal data (name, surnames, etc.).

```
#[ORM\MappedSuperclass]
class Person
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180)]
    private $name;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $surnames;
}
```

And I have a number of entities extending from that one, `Owner`, `Client` and `Visitor` with their own properties, for example:

```
#[ORM\Entity()]
class Owner extends Person
{
    #[ORM\OneToOne(inversedBy: 'owner', targetEntity: User::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private $user;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean')]
    private $isExternal = false;
}
```

My question is, can I create a Person FormType only once and somehow embed it inside the `OwnerFormType`, `ClientFormType` and `VisitorFormType`?

I know I could create a FormType for `Person` and access it separately from `Owner` or `Client` data, save those fields and then complete `Owner` or `Client` in another form, but that leads to problems with required fields, alias it's not an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a form PersonType. Then you create your forms OwnerType,VisitorType etc...
In The builder of the subclasses you can create the PersonType form.

```
$builder
        ->add('user')
        ->add('isExternal')
        ->add('person', PersonType::class, ['data_class' => Owner::class]);
```

Comment: may need `'inherit_data' => true` on the PersonType

Comment: This was almost it, the parameter types [have changed and now the correct form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html) is `$builder->add('person', PersonType::class, ['data_class' => Lawyer::class])`. As @Rufinus sayed, `'inherit_data' => true` must be set on parent form.

Comment: @IX0Y3 I edited your answer to adapt to newer Symfony version, thanks for your response